# Linear operator image is not closed

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

Studying functional analysis, I have to prove that the image of the operator

$S:\ell^1(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow \ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ given by $(S\xi)_n=\xi_n/n$ is not closed, even though $S$ is limited.

Well, I thinked about the sequence

$(\xi_{nj})_j\subset\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ where

$(\xi_{nj})_n$ has the first $n$ entries equals to $1$, the image of this tend to the sequence $(1,1/2,\cdots, 1/n,\cdots)$ and this is not in $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$.

But this is wrong because I has prooved, in fact, that $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ is not complete. To prove the request I need find a sequence that converges to an element of $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ and is not at the image.

At my mind, however, $S$ is surjective, I cannot understand.

Many thanks.

Comment: $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$ _is_ complete.

Comment: Thank you, what about the sequences that converge to the sequence that generates the harmonic serie? I could not understand.

Comment: Is $y = (1/n^2)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in the image? Can you think of a sequence (of sequences) $x_k$ such that $Sx_k\to y$ as $k\to\infty$?

Comment: Sequences $x_k=(1,1/2,...,1/k,0,0,...)$? Sorry by my last comment.

Comment: Very good, Na'omi. That's it.

Comment: And do you see that $(1/n^2)$ is not in the image of $S$?

Comment: Many thanks. Now I am confused about $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ complete...? About this serie

Comment: What is it that confuses you? Please be more precise... Note that $S$ is _not_ surjective!

Comment: About your last comment (1 min ago): I don't have $(n\cdot 1/n^2)=(1/n)\in \ell^1(\mathbb{N})$... right?

Comment: My doubt now is about your comment that $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ is complete. About the sequence of $x_k=(1,1/2,...,1/k,0,0,...)$ that is Cauchy but converges to $(1,1/2,...,1/n,...)$ that doesn't has sum and so is not at $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$. There is error in my though, but I am not able to find this.

Comment: The sequence $x_k$ is not supposed to converge, but $(Sx_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ should converge. And it converges to a $y\in\ell^1$, which is not in the image of $S$.

Comment: I think I undesrtand about the question with S. But yet not about the space be complete... this sequence isn't Cauchy? Many thanks because you helping a lot.

Comment: Right, $(x_k)$ is not Cauchy in $\ell^1$. If it were, it would converge in $\ell^1$ because $\ell^1$ is complete.

Comment: Oh... now I think I understand why is not cauchy... sums $1/n+...+1/(n+m)$ can be as big as we ask... I am sorry for the confusion. Thanks very much.

Comment: That's exactly why, Na'omi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

- $S(1,0,0,0,\ldots)=(1,0,0,0,\ldots)$;
- $S\left(1,\frac12,0,0,\ldots\right)=\left(1,\frac1{2^2},0,0,\ldots\right)$;
- $S\left(1,\frac12,\frac13,0,\ldots\right)=\left(1,\frac1{2^2},\frac1{3^2},0,\ldots\right)$

and so on. So, $S\bigl(\ell^1(\mathbb N)\bigr)$ contains the sequence$$\left(\left(1,\frac1{2^2},\frac1{3^2},\ldots,\frac1{n^2},0,0,\ldots\right)\right)_{n\in\mathbb N},$$but not its limit, which is $\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. So, $S\bigl(\ell^1(\mathbb N)\bigr)$ is not a closed subset of $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$.

Comment: Many thanks. But the limit is at $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ once the harmonic serie doesn't converge?

Comment: But the "limit" is not in $\ell^1$...

Comment: @amsmath My doubt is because I have to prove that subset is not closed with a limit that *is at* the superset and is not at subset... right? (Or did you do this comment to José Carlos?) Many thanks

Comment: @Na'omi I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think is OK now, thanks for attention

Comment: @Na'omi I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Exactly this sequence was already the "answer" in the comments. Not so nice...

Comment: I did not read the comments. Besides, it's a puzzle to my what makes a user who has an answer to post it as a comment instead of posting it as an answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos In order to give hints and make OP think about it. Sometimes they find the answer themselves. Also here, Na'omi did a good job as you can see. And you know by yourself, I guess, that things you figure out yourself remain sticking in your head better than solutions that come from others. That's why. Therefore, in my opinion, one should always first read the comments before giving an answer. Especially when the answer is already (almost) there.

Comment: I forgot to say that when I read the comments and I find an answer there, then I don't answer (unless I am aware of a different answer). On the other hand, there's nothing wrong with posting an answer which consists of a hint.